# Are "here's my code, but I want it to do more, but I have not written that part yet" - on topic?

Tags: discussion

I see at least a few of those low quality questions daily

> Here's my code that does this and that and it works beautifully
>
> `...`
>
> Now I want it to loop through something and fetch some data but I
>   don't know how to do it.
>
> Any help much appreciated. Thanks etc

Is *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved* primarily the correct reason to vote to close these questions?

People tend to think that providing a few lines of what they currently have (or found online) demonstrates a minimal understanding and proves some research has been done but really? it isn't...

Most of the time those questions (if anyone was to answer them) a good few hours of building an app with an explanation of everything - *too broad* as having built an WPF doesn't automatically mean you've implemented the business logic for your app.

How do **you** go about these questions? Do you leave them opened for someone who has the extra time and wants to answer or do you close it as off-topic?

Comment: Close with the reason stated....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on how the questions are linked. If they wrote X (e.g. a data processor), and need help changing it around a bit to do Y (e.g. a slightly modified data processor), they've demonstrated a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. It's generally still necessary to indicate that the user has, at the very least, *attempted* the transition to Y, however, this much is judged is on a case-by-case basis.

If they wrote X (e.g. a server-side script), and need help writing or changing it to perform a totally different function Y (e.g. a client-side script to interface with the server), they haven't demonstrated a minimal understanding of the problem they want solved.

Demonstrating a minimal understanding means demonstrating an understanding of exactly what the problem is they're trying to solve. Using extraneous code to make it *seem* like they know what they're talking about is a common tactic, but it really doesn't count.

If the question matches the latter better than the former, I would vote to close (in my case, flag) as [off-topic:demonstrate minimal understanding].

Comment: Even in your first example, I'd still expect to see an effort made at the modification.

Comment: @Duncan Well... sometimes. It has to be on a case-by-case basis. Very often, the original component `X` is sufficient to demonstrate understanding of the problem. Sometimes it isn't, though.

Answer (score -8):

Yes, you should close such questions if you think that goal of SE is to capitalize on frequent question.

But if you think that the goal is also to attract newbies, wait for one or two days: "someone who has the extra time and wants to answer" might in fact be someone who is used to understanding fast that type of code, and need only one minute to answer with a correct tip.

Example: [How to optimize these FOR loops to save execution time in Matlab script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159719/how-to-optimize-these-for-loops-to-save-execution-time-in-matlab-script/20168235#20168235) (there should be better examples).

Comment: sorry but I can't even express how much I actually disagree.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? is it about "goal is also to attract newbies" ?